# How to remove MenuBar/ select in lwuit form

Tags: lwuit, lwuit-form, lwuit-button

I'm trying to remove this select area which shows up as soon as I add a button to my form.

Have attached a screenshot of the same which might help you understand my plight here. I don't want this select area to appear at the bottom of screen.

Please, any suggestion or any pointer would be of great help.

regards.

[image: After adding the button]

Below is the code which I'm using.(Xlet project)

```
public void showMainForm() {
    try {
        mf = new MainForm();
        mf.createMainForm();
        mf.show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}

public class MainForm extends Form {
MainForm() {
    super();
}
private static Container c;

public void createMainForm() {
    try {
        c = new Container(new CoordinateLayout(800,480));
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.setX(0); btn.setY(0);
        c.addComponent(btn);
        this.getContentPane().addComponent(c);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
}
```

Form code which I tried again...

```
Form frm = new Form();
frm.getStyle().setBgTransparency(0);
//frm.addComponent(new Button("Button"));
frm.show();
```

Comment: If you can share your code we can see whats happening here. Thanks

Comment: Hi, I've added code. Let me know if we need more info. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that this issue can be solved adding the Command to the `Form`,not to the Container as you are doing in the attached code.

**ADD**

I think that I didn't understand what you want to say. Try this code, with my suggestions included

```
    public void showMainForm() {
        try {
            mf = new MainForm();
            mf.createMainForm();
            mf.show();
            } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }

    public class MainForm extends Form {
    MainForm() {
        super();
    }
    private static Container c;

    public void createMainForm() {
        try {
            c = new Container(new CoordinateLayout(800,480));
           // Button btn = new Button();
           // btn.setX(0); btn.setY(0);
             // c.addComponent(btn);
           // this.getContentPane().addComponent(c);
           Command c = new Command("command");
           addCommand(c);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
    }
```

Comment: Hi jmunoz, I tried what you suggested but no luck. See the newly added code which I used. Here, as soon as I uncomment the third line the select space appears at the bottom of the form. Any more suggestion/s...